# Program that outputs URL same with what is provided by the server(PHP,JSON)

Tags: php, json

I am not a programmer so please bear with me.

I created a simple form that will ask for an "ID" and "Links". When I click submit it will display the URL on the second form.

For example I input 12345 in the "ID" and https://www.example1.com in "Links".

The **output.php** form has this code:

```
<script>document.write(window.location);
</script></br>
```

The result using my program is:

> API/output.php?id=12345&links=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example1.com

I want the program result to be like this:

> API/12345.json?blast%5Blinks%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example1.com

Which means that since I input 12345 in the "ID" field, I want to show the result as 12345.json(plus the link) and not output.php(plus the link)

How can I do this?

Comment: If you are not a programmer, its two difficult to do that.Handover this work to any programmer..

Comment: I've been trying to contact a few programmers but most are not answering. probably busy. I understand php but not json.

Comment: Actually solutions for this problem need lot more than just basic php programming. You may need some javascript if you want just rebuild link from url query string Or you may need javascript + apache url rewrite if you want url in browser should also reflect 12345.json.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you have a form that takes `id` and `link` fields, and your result should be `API/id.json?blast[links]=link` (where `id` and `link` come from your form), properly URL encoded.

Try this:

```
<?php

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      $url = $_POST['link'];
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      print 'API/'$id.'.json?blast'.urlencode('[links]='.$url);
  }

?>
```